# Akka web app architecture

Tags: scala, architecture, akka, actor

At the start of the book "Akka in action", the author creates a small WS app with Akka-Http that has Akka actors representing stateful living entity. It is a small ticketing WS Rest service, with one actore acting as the router, another one as a supervisor and one actor per show holding the current tickets available for each shows.

Suppose I want to build a web application around this principle and use an ActorSystem instead of the traditional stateless DB architecture. If my actors holds my live application data as a backend, then I'm having problems for the web app.

Let's say I want to do a website about the ticketing service. I create a MVC web app using play. When the user reach the main page of the site, he has a view of all shows with tickets left, plus shows that are spotlighted near his locations, and some reminders.

When the page loads, the controller will have to ask every actors to get some live data to display the page. Isn't that inefficient ? Isn't it time consuming to send the request for all shows, waiting for all of them to answer, and then displaying the page ?

Should the webapp implement some sort of readmodel of the data that is updated by the actor system instead ? In that case, isn't the duplication of data between actors and DB hard to manage for projects of big size ?

My head is full of questions !

Comment: Never used Akka persistence and I dont even know how it works, but if their persisted state cannot easily be queried then you should probably use CQRS.

Comment: As far as I understood the persisted actor store the events they received and in an append only datastore per actor. So when you restart your actor after a failure for example, it retrieves it's past state.
So you suggest a read model in CQRS ? No live querying actors for their state then ?

Comment: If actors are based on event sourcing then yes, definitely use CQRS and never query through actors. Actors are meant to process commands, no queries.

Comment: @plalx I know it's been 2 years, but do you still subscribe to the "actors vs. queries" notion? If so... do you have some link/code to illustrate. I am genuinely curious.